# What kind of wiki engine does the KDE website use?

Tags: wiki

For example, http://userbase.kde.org or http://techbase.kde.org, what is the wiki they are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> KDE uses [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for its wikis at userbase.kde.org,
>   techbase.kde.org ....

Take a look [here](http://community.kde.org/KDE.org/mediawiki)